# Can you use both OnChanges and DoCheck in an Angular 2 component?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I've got a scenario where I'd wish to use both `ngOnChanges` and `ngDoCheck` in my component, however I remember from some time ago in the angular docs that only one of these should be used at one time.

Although I can no longer seem to find this information, I think it said this somewhere in [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#docheck) section before.

Is it safe to use both of these or do I need to implement my own version of `ngOnChanges` in the `DoCheck` to avoid making a big "no no"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API doc for [ngDoCheck](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html) says

> `ngDoCheck` gets called to check the changes in the directives in addition to the default algorithm.

The Dev Guide [LifeCycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) doc says

> We also see that the `ngOnChanges` method is called in contradiction of the incorrect [API documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html).

But the API doc is correct now.  It [used to state](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/3a62023260e59dafcb57ec12c3be1e3643639347) that if you implemented `ngDoCheck()` then the default algorithm would not be called -- i.e., `ngOnChanges()` would not be called. (So, the Dev Guide is now incorrect for stating that the API docs are incorrect).

It is perfectly fine to implement both.